# Batch file - stops in the middle of running

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to learn Batch.

I wrote a simple code with two labels.

This is the code:

```
@echo off 
title intro

color 1f

::############################
::label
:one
cls
echo hello
echo. please enter your First name
echo.
:: fname is a variable (type p - string) that will content the user input. the input will be insert after <<
set /p fname= ">>" 
echo.
echo. please enter your Last name
set /p lname=">>" 
echo.
echo hello %fname% %lname%!

pause>nul
goto two

::############################
:two
cls 
echo. welcome to page two
```

After the command line prints "hello  ", it waits for the user response. if the user hits enter, instead of continuing to label "two", the command line closes.

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: when user press enter it actually continues to label two, but it is not visible to human eye , execution is fast makes this happen , instead execute the script from a command prompt to get the expected output or add a pause at the end of your script and check.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because it exits when the script comes to and end and has nothing more to do.

Add for example a `pause` at the very end of your script

Like this

```
echo. welcome to page two
pause
```

Then all you want on "page two" will be between your `welcome to page two` and `pause`

Answer (score 1):

You don't say whether you are executing that batch from the prompt or from a shortcut"

After showing hello *names entered* the batch stops at the `pause`, and waits for an <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The `>nul` suppresses the prompt `Press any key to continue . . .`

batch will then continue to `:two` (the `goto` is redundant) but if you executed the routine from a "shortcut" the batch window will appear to close immediately as reaching end-of-file terminates the routine.